# My Mac is resizing photos I save to the desktop exporting from Lightroom Classic

Tags: photos

My Mac is resizing my photos that I export from Lightroom Classic. I set the export to be 800 x 500 but when I open them up or send them via email, they are 753 x 502.  How can I stop this from happening.  And yes, I know I can resize them in preview but I would like to be able to skip this step.

Comment: is this the mac mail client?  It can (or not) resize emails on send.  You can confirm the real size of the exported file from finder (check Info for PNGs) or use `sips` from the command line.. eg. `sips -g pixelWidth -g pixelHeight FileToTest.jpg`

Comment: This happens before I send them or put them in an email. This happens when I put them on the desktop (either on my laptop or in the cloud).

Comment: What are the original dimensions?  Do you change the DPI/PPI?  I would guess your mac isn't changing anything - ie. what you are seeing is whatever Lightroom is doing on export ...